# skewed separation in css

Tags: css, frontend, diagonal

So I was trying to make a skewed separation in CSS (only). It should look kind of like this here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVCa1.png

I tried it with CSS transforms already (`transform: skew(-15deg);`), but I don't think it'll work in all browsers, and it's not really adaptive. I thought about making it with linear gradients, but I'm not sure if this is any better.

Do you guys know of any better solution for this?

EDIT: here's the code:

```
.results {
  width: 500px; }

.transf {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox */
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-15deg);
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  background: grey !important;
  width: 6px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  z-index: 1; }

.left_border {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox */
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-15deg);
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  background: yellow;
  border-right: 1px solid green;
  border-top: 1px solid green;
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  width: 10px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  z-index: 2; }

.right_border {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox */
  display: inline-block;
  -moz-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-15deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-15deg);
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  background: orange;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  width: 10px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  z-index: 2; }

.left {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox */
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  z-index: 0; }

.right {
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox */
  display: inline-block;
  background: orange;
  width: 20%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 0; }

.item21 {
  width: 5%; }

.item22 {
  width: 15%; }
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="results">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="left_border"></div>
    <div class="transf"></div>
    <div class="right_border"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="results">
    <div class="left item21"></div>
    <div class="left_border"></div>
    <div class="transf"></div>
    <div class="right_border"></div>
    <div class="right item22"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have pointed out, this can be done with CSS3 only, but not all browsers support it. For full browser support i'd use jQuery

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/UkAfD/26/

```
var skewed = false;
function skew() {
    skewed = !skewed;        
    $('#box').css({
        skewY: skewed ? '10deg' : '-10deg'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could do.

- You could use transforms with a polyfill like [CSSSandpaper](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/csssandpaper-a-css3-javascript-library/) to
  make it cross browser compatible. Although, to get that type of
  separation (with one side of the div being straight) you may have to
  use skew AND [perspective](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html).
- You could make a faux separator by using the before and after
  pseudo classes with the [CSS triangle trick](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/). This, too, would
  require a polyfill for pseudo classes like [Selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com/). You
  would also have to play around with the `border-width` values to get
  it to match what you are looking for.
- You could use a PNG using the before/after pseudo classes.
- You could use [SVG](http://www.w3schools.com/svg/svg_rect.asp) to draw the borders around the containers.

Any of these would work, but its definitely not as easy as, say, rounded corners or drop shadows. You need to put in a little extra work to get those types of results.